# Why didn't we pluralize the abbreviated form in the sentence below in spite of the non-abbreviated form being pluralized?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, abbreviations, initialisms

> Of the nine traction power sub-stations (TPSS), five shall be equipped with four DC feeders and four shall be equipped with six DC feeders.

the above sentence is an example in the book ' Writing in the Technical field' by Thorsten Ewald
but in the next sentence, they have added an extra "s" while writing the abbreviated form

> The light rail system will include nine TPSSs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bracketed abbreviation could be read as

> ... (in this paper I will abbreviate "traction power sub-station" as TPSS)...

The bracket acts like a little dictionary definition, and normally one defines words in their singular form.

The bracketed abbreviation is not part of the grammatical structure of the sentence. It doesn't obviously have to mean the plural. The simplest base form of the abbreviation seems to be the best choice here.

Answer (score 2):

If a noun phrase is plural, then the acronym that follows it in parentheses is usually plural, too:

> Of the nine traction power sub-stations (TPSSs), . . .

That plural form would be consistent with the plural form in the next sentence:

> The light rail system will include nine TPSSs.

However, some people (I believe a minority) prefer always to give the "base" form of the acronym when it is first introduced. That appears to be what happened in your example.

By the way, you may be interested in this similar EL&U question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583263/is-an-acronym-initialism-ever-pluralized-in-its-parenthetical-introduction.

Answer (score 1):

**In news, technical and academic writing, the first occurrence of the abbreviation of a term is often placed right after the word.**

This is the case here. TPSS is the abbreviation and they place it right after they spell it  out in full.

Now, the reader will know that TPSS stands for traction power sub-station.

**When they mention it again, they now use the plural with an s to mean more than one TPSS.**

Another example:

There was an intercontinental ballistic missile (**ICBM**) in the warehouse.
However, **ICBMs** are often stored by groups of five in warehouses.

Here is the rule spelled out by the New  York Times:

> **But do not use apostrophes for plurals of abbreviations without periods, or for plurals formed from figures: TVs, PCs, DVDs; 1990s,
> 747s, size 7s.**

[New York Time style guidelines](https://archive.nytimes.com/afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/04/13/faqs-on-style/)

> Form the plural of abbreviations by adding a lower-case s without an
> apostrophe, e.g. ICBMs not ICBM s or ICBMS.

[newsroom style guidelines](https://areenaarora.com/comparing-newsrooms-styleguides/)